# Find Distance between different coordinates

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, geocoding

I have Location data (latitude and longitude) of 1000's of locations and need to compute the distance between each of them taken two combinations at a time.

Example:

Let's just say I have four location data (latitude and longitude data) and want to compute the distance between them

```
    Location      Latitude    Longitude

 1. New York(L1)  40.7128° N  74.0060° W
 2. Paris(L2)     48.8566° N   2.3522° E
 3. London(L3)    51.5074° N   0.1278° W
 4. Moscow(L4)    55.7558° N  37.6173° E
```

Need to calculate the distance between possible combinations i.e distance between `L1&L2`, `L1&L3`, `L1&L4`, `L2&L3`, `L2&L4` and `L3&L4`

Excel Formula I'm using to compute distance is

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) *COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) *6371
```

How can I calculate it for large data set say 100's or 1000's of locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can create a VBA function and then loop through your table.

Add this code to a Module in the VBA editor:

```
Public Function DistBetweenCoord(Lat1 As Double, Long1 As Double, Lat2 As Double, Long2 As Double)
    'Cell Formula
    'ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) *COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) *6371

    With WorksheetFunction
        A = Cos(.Radians(90 - Lat1))
        B = Cos(.Radians(90 - Lat2))
        C = Sin(.Radians(90 - Lat1))
        D = Sin(.Radians(90 - Lat2))
        E = Cos(.Radians(Long1 - Long2))

        DistBetweenCoord = .Acos(A * B + C * D * E) * 6371
    End With
End Function
```

Now you can access this through code or in cell.  Here is an example of in-cell:

```
=DistBetweenCoord(C1,D1,C2,D2)
```

---

Here is how to loop through all possible combinations in another Sub.  Output is in immediate window.

```
Sub CalcAllDistances()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 4
            For j = i To 4
                If i <> j Then
                    Debug.Print .Cells(i, 2) & " to " & .Cells(j, 2) & ": " & DistBetweenCoord(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 4), .Cells(j, 3), .Cells(j, 4))
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** - To change output to Sheet2 try the following:

```
Sub CalcAllDistances()
    Dim wks_Output As Worksheet
    Set wks_Output = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim OutputRow As Long: OutputRow = 1

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 4
            For j = i To 4
                If i <> j Then
                    wks_Output.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 2) & " to " & .Cells(j, 2)
                    wks_Output.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = DistBetweenCoord(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, 4), .Cells(j, 3), .Cells(j, 4))
                    OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Getting Invalid Name error while applying "=DistBetweenCoord(C1,D1,C2,D2)" formula in cell

Comment: That probably means it can't find the function.  Did you add the function into a Module or the worksheet code?  It won't work if located in the worksheet code.

Comment: Yes now formula working in cell
can you elaborate on Sub CalcAllDistances part and how to get Immediate window

Comment: Sure, when in VBA editor (ALT+F11) you can show Immediate window by View->Immediate Window or by CTRL+G

Comment: Thanks
Works great but its limited to four location entries only right 
How can I extend it to say 100's or 1000's of entries?

Comment: Change the `To 4` to how ever many rows you have.  ie. `To 1000`  Make sure you do it for both lines of code `For i = 1 To 1000` & `For j = i To 1000`

Comment: Getting Run-time error '1004; - Unable to get the Acos Property of the worksheetFunction class - when ran for 1000 entries

Comment: Make sure you don't have any empty cells in those 1000 rows.  When error happens, go to debugger and see what row you are on (i & j values).  Make sure that data is formatted correctly.  There are no error handlers in this code.

Comment: Output Immediate isn't storing entries more than 200
which means I have to make i,j values less than 20
Is there a way to increase the limit of Immediate so that it can store atleast 10000?

Comment: See edit, I added a modified version to output results to Sheet2.

Comment: Getting Run-time error '6: Over flow, 
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W4Y80rXdYiusX_y2T_LRNoJoLLJb6Xlux1q6Eq7jvrE/edit?usp=sharing)
 contains sample excel sheet with almost 1000+ places entries
when I tried 'edit' code I'm getting overflow error
Can you check it out once?

Comment: Had trouble downloading it but I don't see a Sheet2 in the version I could get.  It didn't include your code so I couldn't check.  Make sure you add a new sheet and that it's called "Sheet2"

Comment: I forgot to add sheet2 in that link.


Run-time error '6: Over flow,  when used debug it's pointing out to "OutputRow = OutputRow + 1" and Outpur Row = 32767 when placing cursor on it .

Comment: My bad... You have too many rows for the memory limit of Integer.  Change `Dim OutputRow As Integer` to `Dim OutputRow As Long`  "Long" type will give you over 2 billion rows.

Comment: Getting Run-time error '1004; - Unable to get the Acos Property of the worksheetFunction class and Debug is pointing out to 'DistBetweenCoord = .Acos(A * B + C * D * E) * 6371'

Answer (score 2):

I would use a matrix.
Create a sheet (like 'GeocodeList' or something) for the geocodes, like your city|lat|lon in the question. Then create a sheet (like 'Distances') for a matrix, where the column and row labels are the city names. Then you can parameter your excel formula using V.LOOKUPs that look up exact codes from GeocodeList.

The formula would look like this (X is row number, Y is column letter.):

```
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-VLOOKUP($A(X); GEOCODETABLE, LATCOLINDEX, 0)))
*COS(RADIANS(90-VLOOKUP((Y)$1; GEOCODETABLE; LATCOLINDEX, 0)))
+SIN(RADIANS(90-VLOOKUP($A(X); GEOCODETABLE, LATCOLINDEX, 0)))
*SIN(RADIANS(90-VLOOKUP((Y)$1; GEOCODETABLE; LATCOLINDEX, 0)))
*COS(RADIANS(VLOOKUP($A(X); GEOCODETABLE, LATCOLINDEX, 0)-VLOOKUP((Y)$1; GEOCODETABLE; LONCOLINDEX, 0))))
*6371
```

So basically the VLOOKUP automatically fetches your parameters, and you can extend the formula for the whole matrix.

Comment: Created two sheets
sheet1: GeocodeList- that contains city names as colum1 latitude Data as column2 longitude data as column3
sheet2: Distances- that contains city names from A2: A5 and B1: E1

didn't understand VLOOKUP formula can you elaborate it ?

Comment: VLOOKUP returns the value in the xth column of the lookup table, where the first column's value equals your lookup value.
So when your vlookup looks like
VLOOKUP($A2; 'GeocodeList'!$A:$C;2;0)
the formula will return tha value in the 2nd column (col B) of sheet GeocodeList, where the first column in GeocodeList (col A) equals your lookup value (A2 on the Distances sheet)
So if A2 in 'Distances' is 'New York', and on 'GeocodeList' A3 is 'New York', you will get New York's latitude (from 'GeocodeList' B3)

Comment: Note: the '0' at the end of the vlookup formula means it must find an exact match for the lookup value